# How to delete images of Photos in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am importing images of photos of device in application.

I display all the images selected by user from photos.

I stored this images into document directory and image path into database.

Now the problem is when user completed selection of images from photos after completion i have to ask them for delete images from photos.Now if user press delete how can i delete those images.

I stored that selected images in document directory for application requirement.

Also if selected images are deleted from photos then how can i export that images into photos?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why you want to store those images in document directory anyway it's on photos app in device locally. If it would have been the case of syncing between any server images or your device images, then question make sense.

Comment: i did it for security purpose if i delete images from photos then in my application i can access those photos which are stored in document direcotry.

Comment: Then why you want indication by photos app that app had deleted these short of images? You can save those in document directory and you shouldn't be bother how much images deleted from photos ap

Comment: But i want to make image secure, in photos anyone can access available photos. If i deleted them from photos then only from my application can access that photos. In photos it was not seen to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Delete asset from library
      [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:assetArray];

    } completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: Where's `PHPhotoLibrary ` ?

Comment: @import Photos; library into application.. For more information visit this link->https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PHPhotoLibrary

Comment: only one image delete or whole album delete

Comment: @RamaniHitesh You can pass array of images or single item also.